# Jade template each loop to include jade file

Tags: node.js, pug

In the jade template engine:
 -can i do a each loop to include files? For e.g.

```
each val in ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
     include val
```

Comment: why you don't try it?

Comment: It does not work. Is there an alternative though? Or do I have to include them one by one.

Comment: why you want to do this in a loop? and what is the content of your files?

Comment: just so it looks better. and im writting less. they are jade files

Comment: @timaschew please either provide a solution or refrain from commenting. OP wants to iterate over an array and include files at each element's path. It is irrelevant whether or not jade is commonly used to do something else.

Comment: if you want to include jade files dynamically, you should do it not within the template, do it in the scope above, for instance in express

Answer (score 2):

**"You are trying to include files dynamically through a loop. Dynamic inclusion is not supported."**
From the Jade issues section on Github: https://github.com/pugjs/jade/issues/1924