# Jade: Include a list of markdown files

Tags: node.js, pug, markdown

I'm trying to render a list of markdown files in a jade template, but it doesn't work.

Feeding the data to the jade file is working just fine, as I can for example, replace the second line in the jade file with `p= folder1` and that will give me two paragraphs, both containing a list of the two files.

Likewise, replacing the `file` with `folder1/md1-1.md` will render that file twice.

**index.jade**:

```
each file in folder1
  include:markdown file
```

**gulpfile.js** (markup part)

```
gulp.task('markup', function(){
  return gulp.src(['./src/jade/**/*.jade'])
    .pipe(data(function(file) {
      return require('./src/jade/md.json');
    }))
    .pipe(jade({ pretty: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});
```

**md.json**

```
{
  "folder1": [
    "folder1/md1-1.md",
    "folder1/md1-2.md"
  ],
  "folder2": [
    "folder2/md2-1.md",
    "folder2/md2-2.md"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you make it finally?

Comment: Sadly not. IIRC I saw that someone somewhere said that you can't do includes like that - you can only do it in a hardcoded manner. I went with a more boilerplate solution instead, as a dynamic system like this wasn't exactly necessary for my project.

Comment: Solved in [Jade template each loop to include jade file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141365/jade-template-each-loop-to-include-jade-file?rq=1) -- dynamic inclusion is not supported.

Comment: Jade has changed name to Pug, so this may be relevant to Pug as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jade template each loop to include jade file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141365/jade-template-each-loop-to-include-jade-file)